# How to run 2 ajax request with 2 different actions using the same data in jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a function that contain 2 $.ajax functions with different actions but using same  data
i put these data inside an object, how to add different action to every $.ajax function

it's mandatory to use same  data inside an object

```
var request_data = {
            nonce: ajax_object.nonce, 
            category_id: cat_ids,
            brand_name: brand_name_value,
            orderby_meta_key: orderby_meta_key,
            orderby: orderby,
            order_type: order_type,
            shop_view: shop_view
        } 

    function ajax_filter(){

// firest ajax function       
        $.ajax( {
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            action:'shop_filter',   ------> //not working like this
            data: request_data,
            success: function(feedback) {
            }
        })
            
// second ajax function
       $.ajax( {
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            action: 'update_another_function',   ----> //not working like this
            cache: true,
            data: request_data,
            success: function(feedback) {
            },
        })

    }
```

Comment: If you are posting the SAME information to the SAME URL after each other, why not just run the functions on the server side in the first call?

Comment: What is `action` supposed to be - key/value POSTed data?  Shouldn't it be in `request_data`?

Comment: The action is the name of server side function the  two ajax function will send requests to 2 different server sidefunction but the data will be the same

Comment: The usual (and simplest) way to do that is to have them POST to different URLs.  If you don't have that option, or you want to make things a bit more complicated, you could use the same URL/method, and make that method some kind of router, which checks the POSTed data to find out which method to call to handle the request.  In this case `action` would be part of the POSTed data, so just another `request_data` key/value pair.  @Musa's answer below is a clear example of how to do the front end part of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no action parameter in jQuery.ajax, should your action be in the request data?

```
function ajax_filter(){
   request_data.action = 'shop_filter';
// firest ajax function       
    $.ajax( {
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: request_data,
        success: function(feedback) {
        }
    })
   request_data.action = 'update_another_function';     
// second ajax function
   $.ajax( {
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        cache: true,
        data: request_data,
        success: function(feedback) {
        },
    })

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change action outside the request_data?

Comment: Depends on what the server side code looks like